# Draw a CNN architecture in Latex

Tags: cnn

Is there a way that I can draw a simple CNN architecture in LaTeX if I know that my model has: four convolutions, three blocks (convolution + BN + RELU + dropout), and then pooling after each layer?

Then lastly a normal convolution Conv2d.